# I cannot to clear up an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found here a topic about emptying an array in JS, but I am not allowed to post there. I have to ask here.
Here is my code:

```
sumarray.length=0;
 sumarray = [];
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
      sumarray.push(i);
  console.log('***1***:',sumarray.length, sumarray);
  var t;
  while (console.log('***2***: t:',t=sumarray.pop()) || t!==undefined) {
      console.log('***3***:',sumarray.length,sumarray);
    }
 console.log('*****4***: ',sumarray.length, sumarray);
```

And this is what I see in the log

[image]

I did not assign the global sumarray array to any other variable.How I can get rid of the trash in it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'trash'?

Comment: `sumarray.length=0; sumarray = [];` If `sumarray` exists and is an array beforehand, the first instruction is redundant. If it exists but is not an array, it is useless. If it doesn't exist, it is invalid. There is no scenario where it serves a purpose. Meanwhile, your output is impossible given the code you gave us (the array contains some game objects, not `[1,2,3]`), so if your code is wrong about generating `sumarray`, I can't have confidence it is not wrong somewhere else, too. Your code as pasted does result in an empty `sumarray`, unless you have redefined `pop` or somesuch.

Comment: What's going on here? `while (console.log('***2***: t:',t=sumarray.pop())..`?

Comment: @Andy: It's not readable but valid: `console.log` returns `undefined`, so `(console.log(value1) || value2)` displays `value1` then evaluates to `value2`.

Comment: @Amadan, yeah, it was really a question for the OP, but thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for voting down my question. If you got confused by it, it does not mean that question is not valid?

Comment: 1. Xzandro -By 'trash' I mean totally irrelevant log. It shows objects, even when array supposed to be empty or having only '1','2','3'.   2.Amadan sumarray.length =0; sumarray=[]; The first instruction is redudant, of course. I just tried to use all known to me methods to empty the array. I don't get any errors.  3,4. Andy,Amadan- seems you figure out by yourself. I wanted to see what I am trowing from the array .   6. It is not OOP - did you mean OOP?

Comment: '0','1','2' - not 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **delete** keyword . Look Below

Example:

```
var summary = ["x","y","z"];
```

then

```
  for(var i=0; i < summary.length; i++){
    delete summary[i];
    }
```

--Update

**delete** will return an array with an occupied length of undefined but will keep the indexes .

you can still use pop to remove the indexed completely:

```
for(var i=0; i < summary.length; i++){
        summary.pop(i);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea - The first method did not help - I see the same log. The second I have already used.

Comment: It's the same after rebooting the comp. :(